# Hide / Show a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div toggle its visibility when a button is clicked. Currently I can hide the div, but I'm having trouble making it visible again.

```
function unhide(divID) {
//var item = document.getElementById(divID);
//if (item) {
//    item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
//    $('#SearchParParams').toggle()
//}
var group = $('.group'),
target = group.filter('#' + divID);

if (target.className =='group hidden') {
    group.removeClass('unhidden').addClass('hidden');
    target.addClass('unhidden').removeClass('hidden');
    target.length == 0;
}
if (target.className == 'group unhidden') {
    group.removeClass('hidden').addClass('unhidden');
    target.addClass('hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    target.length = 1;
}

//$('#SearchAddParams,#SearchParParams').click(function () {
//    $('#SearchParParams, #SearchAddParams').toggle();
//});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying too hard. If you want to show and hide an element onClick, you can use toggle().

```
//When you click this button
$('button').click(function(){
//Show or hide this div, depending on its state
    $('div').toggle();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8jfdxg5/)

Comment: but i want the information to be hidden at first since this is tying into three searches that are different, would the hidden element work for this?

Comment: You set the element to hidden using CSS or JS. For example `div{display:none;}`

Comment: if you want to control hiding it with css (ie `visibility:hidden`) you can also use `$('div').toggleClass('hidden');` to simply toggle a class.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```html
if (target.className == 'group unhidden') {
    group.removeClass('hidden').addClass('unhidden');
    target.addClass('hidden').removeClass('unhidden');
    target.length = 1;
}
```

Not sure if this fixes the issue but this change definitely needs to be made.